# Regular Expression to match sentence that end with special characters like . ! ? but ignore words like George W. Bush,Mr. etc

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to parse a text file in which the sentences end with special characters like `.`, `!` and `?` but ignore words like George W. Bush, Mr. Hopkins Mrs. Violet etc.

I tried `(?!Mr|Mrs|[A-Za-z]\.\s)\S.+?[.!?](?=\s+|$)` but this doesn't not seem to be working.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with regular expressions unless you restrict the abbreviations (W., Mr., ...) to a limited set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex can not intelligently recognise what is an abbreviation and what is the end of the sentence.

What regex can do, is to define a set of characters that mark the end of the sentence and are therefore not matched and to define a set of exceptions when those characters should be matched anyway.

Try:

```
([^.!?]|(?<=etc|Dr|Mr|Mrs|\b[A-Za-z]|\s)[.!?])+
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?34sva).

This will **not match** the chars `.!?`

But will match those chars anyway when they are preceeded by something out of this alternation `etc|Dr|Mr|Mrs|\b[A-Za-z]|\s`

Comment: The expression works absolutely fine, only that when sentences such as  "This is a difficult sentence because I use I.D. Newlines should also be accepted Numbers should not cause sentence breaks, like 1.23." the output I get is " This is a difficult sentence because I use I.D. Newlines should also be accepted
 Numbers should not cause sentence breaks, like 1
23" What would you suggest?

Comment: Add that case to the alternation `([^.!?]|(?<=etc|Dr|Mr|Mrs|\b[A-Za-z]|\s)[.!?]|(?<=\d)\.(?=\d))+`. [Regexr](http://regexr.com?34t13)

Comment: Also can I replace \d with \w to match input such as I.D. also?

Comment: You can, but that should already be matched by the part `\b[A-Za-z]`. Is it not working?

Comment: It is not matching I.D. I want it to split at I.D. but it results in "because I use I.D. Sentence should not break at 1.23. "

Comment: [^.!?] splits Hello World! How are you? into Hello World! and How are you? what if I want to consider ! followed by a space and not split just at !

Comment: Nope. That is now the point, where it gets impossible. If you don't want to split on `!` remove it from the first character class. But how should the pattern know that this is not the end of a sentence, and another `!` does end a sentence?

Comment: hmm no worries. But why do you think \b[A-Za-z] is not splitting f I.D. or A.B.C.

Comment: Because it allows a `.!?` with exactly one letter before it, the `(?<=etc|Dr|Mr|Mrs|\b[A-Za-z]|\s)[.!?]` part.

Comment: Thank you so much for everything. If you come up with something for the minor pending issues like splitting after D in I.D.  and split when a special character is followed by a space like ! and not just at ! Please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

English is a decidedly non-regular language. I don't think a regex will be sufficient: you'll probably need a full tokenizer, plus some kind of machine learning, possibly a Markov model, to detect where one sentence ends and the next begins. And even then it would only be a heuristic -- since human language use is sloppy, an exact solution may never be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no regex expert, but I found this regex to work well at identifying breaks *between* sentences.

`(?<!\b\p{Upper}\w{0,4})(?=[.?!]\s*\p{Upper})[.?!]\s*`

It looks for sentence punctuation followed by a capital letter, excluding where there is a word beginning with a capital, because titles are capitalized.

Also note this is java regex, so `\p{Upper}` might not work.

Also, the title length of 4 is arbitrary, regex requires a fixed length for lookback, and I couldn't think any title abbreviations longer than 4 characters.

Let me break it down for anyone learning regex.

```
# Don't match where we have a short word beginning with a capital (for titles)
(?<!\b\p{Upper}\w{0,4}) 

(?=[.?!]\s*\p{Upper}) # Only match when followed by a captial. (for abbreviations)

[.?!] #match the punctuation

\s* #also match white space, so no trimming is required (optional)
```

And here's a nonsense testing paragraph that puts this regex through the ropes:

`This is a sentence. I really want to win, etc. and win more. This is pretty neat. I want to thank Mr. Shea for his work. Mr. Hugo helped as well. M. Thénardier is thankful as well. The wonderful Mr. Albert Einstien PhD. is a cool dude as well.`

Edit: I've been thinking about this, and I've found one case where this regex doesn't work. Consider this phrase:

`Joey loved talking to Max. This was because Max is his best friend.`

In this example, `Max. This` is picked up as a name and title. This only works with short names (under five characters with `\w{0,4}`, the `4` could be adjusted to something smaller to filter out longer titles) I can't think of any way to fix this other than learning what words are name or titles. I guess my method is't perfect, but I think it's close enough for most circumstances.