# Include the period in a sentence - regular expression

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, divide

I have 40,000 lines and need to divide each line into different sentences. Now I'm using pattern like this:

```
String patternStr2 = "\\s*[\"']?\\s*([A-Z0-9].*?[\\.\\?!]\\s)['\"]?\\s*";
```

It can handle almost all the sentences, but for sentences like this:
U.S. Navy, World War I. 
would be divided into 2 part: U.S. and Navy, World War I.

Is there any solution to handle this problem?

Comment: It really sounds like you need context sensitive matching, which cannot be done with regular expressions.

Comment: Unless you only want to handle `U.S.` (and **no** other acronym), which can be done fairly easily :D

Comment: As an alternative to smartly trying to understand where the end of the sentence belongs, you could try hand putting in the cases where the basic period ending fails.

Comment: I answered some minutes ago a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16581620/626273), maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String patternStr2 = "`(?<!\\..)(?<![A-Z].)[\\.\\?!](?!.\\.)`"; then by using java Matcher find() method, all the sentences can be got.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think you should **not** use regex for this, but I couldn't resist throwing in some.

If this is hard to understand let me know and I'll add some comments...

```
package test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    private static final Pattern SENTENCE_DELIMITER = 
            Pattern.compile("((.+?)((?<!\\.[A-Z])(\\.\\s)(.+))?)");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String lineWithOneSentence = 
                "U.S. Navy, World War I";
        String lineWithTwoSentences = 
                "U.S. Navy, World War I. U.S. Air Force, World War III.";
        Matcher matcher = SENTENCE_DELIMITER.matcher(lineWithOneSentence);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                switch (i) {
                case 0: 
                    System.out.println("WHOLE MATCH: " + matcher.group(i));
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    System.out.println("FIRST SENTENCE: "+ matcher.group(i));
                    break;
                case 5: 
                    System.out.println("SECOND SENTENCE: " + matcher.group(i));
                default:
                }

            }
        }
        matcher = SENTENCE_DELIMITER.matcher(lineWithTwoSentences);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                switch (i) {
                case 0: 
                    System.out.println("WHOLE MATCH: " + matcher.group(i));
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    System.out.println("FIRST SENTENCE: "+ matcher.group(i));
                    break;
                case 5: 
                    System.out.println("SECOND SENTENCE: " + matcher.group(i));
                default:
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The workaround here is to:

- Use groups
- Use a negative lookbehind for dots followed by a space, to ensure they are not preceded by a dot followed by a capital letter (as in "U**.S**._")

This is rather overkill and will probably be a problem at some point, i.e. if your text is not coherent as per punctuation.

---

**Ouput**:

```
WHOLE MATCH: U.S. Navy, World War I
FIRST SENTENCE: U.S. Navy, World War I
SECOND SENTENCE: null
WHOLE MATCH: U.S. Navy, World War I. U.S. Air Force, World War III.
FIRST SENTENCE: U.S. Navy, World War I
SECOND SENTENCE: U.S. Air Force, World War III.
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to *match* while you want to *split* ?

Use the following regex:

`(?<!\..)\.(?!.\.)`

**Explanation:**

1. `(?<!\..)`: Negative lookbehind, check if there is no point 2 characters behind.
2. `\.`: Match a point.
3. `(?!.\.)`: Negative look ahead, check if there is no point 2 characters ahead.

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/fD1gD2)

**Note:** Not sure how to do this in JAVA, but I think you should try `(?<!\\..)\\.(?!.\\.)`. Also don't forget to *add* a point to your splitted sentences.

Comment: This is a really great hint, but cannot handle sentences like "Dr.Wu is perfect". So, I have made a little change, String patternStr2 = "(?<!\\..)(?<![A-Z].)[\\.\\?!](?!.\\.)"; then by using java Matcher find() method, all the sentences can be got. Anyway, many many thanks for this answer!!